# backbone.js - using parse without calling fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

On page load I'm bootstrapping my data to my collections via [this technique](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap). That works great, but I'm running into an issue where I have sub-models which also need to be cast.

For example, I return a JSON collection called Book, and each book array contains 10-20 models themselves called Pages. If I try and access Pages directly, I get the `[object][object]` error as Backbone can't figure out what type of object it is.

Previously when I was using `fetch`, I would get around this by using collections which contained a `parse` action. In `parse` I would do something like:

```
Collection_Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Model_Book,
    parse: function (response) {
        response.Pages = new Collection_Pages(response.Pages);
        return response;
    }
});
```

Now that I'm accessing the data directly and not using `fetch`, the documentation implies that I no longer have access to the `parse` method.

If I am not using `fetch` or calling a server on page load, how can I cast sub-models using the Books > Pages example?

Comment: If you're ok adjusting your constructor/initialize method a little bit, you can certainly set up child models there. A little more detail towards the end of this post: http://bit.ly/KKHItJ

Comment: Your _this technique_ link is broken

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**: This answer is now out of date, see [uglymunky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14950519/479863) for more up to date information.

---

You're right, `parse` is [only specified to be called during `fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) so it won't be called when you're building a collection from raw data.

But, since you control the raw data that you're using to bootstrap your collection, you can call your collection's `parse` yourself:

```
var c = new YourCollection(
    YourCollection.prototype.parse([
        // attribute data goes here...
    ])
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kdaZ3/

Your `parse` methods (both collection and model) shouldn't care about their calling context so calling them directly from the prototype should be fine.

Comment: I think this is about the third time you've bailed me out with backbone.js. I owe you a thanks yet again :)

Answer (score 57):

Not sure if this is new, but it looks like you can also just set the `parse` property of the options parameter to your constructor to true, thus telling the constructor to use your parse method:

```
modelInstance = new MyModel(obj, {parse: true});
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor

Comment: Note: this works on the collection constructor as well e.g. var books = new Collection_Books(json, {parse: true});

Comment: This is new behavior, Backbone didn't have this option when the question was asked. I guess we will just have to wait around until the "accept" gets switched.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for calling the Collections parse, only each of the Model's parses. You would think `new Collection_Books(json, {parse: true});` would call `YourCollection.prototype.parse` but it does not. so this answer cannot be correct.